# Machine learning model keeps on giving the same result even with different outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

```
my_dict = {'Stype': {'black': 1, 'clayey': 2, 'loamy': 3, 'red': 4, 'sandy': 5},
          'Ph': {'extremely acidic': 1, 'moderately acidic': 2, 'moderately alkaline': 3, 'neutral': 4, 'slightly acidic': 5, 'slightly alkaline': 6, 'strongly acidic': 7, 'strongly alkaline': 8, 'very strongly acidic': 9, 'very strongly alkaline': 10},
          }
    
labels = cropname['Stype'].astype('category').cat.categories.tolist()
replace1 = {'Stype': {k: v for k,v in zip(labels, list(range(1,len(labels) + 1)))}}
print(replace1)

labels1 = cropname['Ph'].astype('category').cat.categories.tolist()
replace2 = {'Ph': {k: v for k,v in zip(labels1, list(range(1,len(labels1) + 1)))}}
print(replace2)

cropname_replace = cropname.copy()

cropname_replace.replace(replace1, inplace=True)
cropname_replace.replace(replace2, inplace=True)
print(cropname_replace.head())
```

The output I get from above program is:

```
   Temparature  Humidity   Moisture  Stype suitable-crop  Ph
0           26         52        38      5         Maize   5
1           32         62        34      4   Ground Nuts   4
2           29         52        45      3     Sugarcane   6
3           34         65        62      1        Cotton   2
4           26         14        35      5        Barley   4
```

I then fit my model with random forest model

```
y = cropname_replace['suitable-crop']
X = cropname_replace.drop(columns=['suitable-crop'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_tain, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier()

model = model.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

The model is also giving an accuracy of 0.9 value. But when I pass it inputs it keeps on giving the result 'Barley'.

```
pd.to_pickle(model,r'Desktop')
model = pd.read_pickle(r'Desktop')

Soiltype = input('Enter the soil type:').lower()
pH = input('Enter the pH type:').lower()
Temperature = input('Enter temperature:')
Humidity = input('Eneter Humidity:')
Moisture = input('Enter moisture:')


Stype1 = (my_dict['Stype'][Soiltype])

pH1 = (my_dict['Ph'][pH])

result = model.predict([[Stype1, pH1, Temperature, Humidity, Moisture]])
print(result)
```

[This is the SS of my outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0JeN.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWuDF.png)

[The dataset is given here:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V860CACmtrjNlGm3pC7IVG-1z3xa-G6k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: if you create the instance of a model once then it will give the same results for different training loops because the model's weights will be stored in the cache. What you need to do is run the cell where you create the instance of a model before coming to the training part. That's what fixes the error in jupyter. if you still have errors then I don't know.

Comment: It actually worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `jupyter-notebook`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: It was done in jupyter-notebook. so, I mentioned the tag. Sorry if it came out to be irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X_train, y_train = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=5,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)
model = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

pls, also refer:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html

Comment: I tried doing that and now the accuracy shown is zero.